What does "parameterised type in the positive / negative position" mean in the context of invariant functors?
From PureScript's Data.Functor.Invariant documentation (emphasis mine):

A type of functor that can be used to adapt the type of a wrapped function where the parameterised type occurs in both the positive and negative position, for example, F (a -> a).

What do the terms "positive" and "negative position" refer to above?
.. and also wondering why F (a -> a) requires an entirely new type of functor, but that should be another question probably..
I tried to figure this out both by learning more about invariant functors and looking up the terms "positive", "negative" in connection with functional programming, but wasn't able to connect the dots yet. Is there a basic resource that I've missed? Or, at least, where should one start to understand these concepts? (Not even sure what the right topic is; see my research attempts below.)

From the search results for
"invariant functor positive negative"
, "positively invariant vs negatively invariant polarity"
, "type theory positive negative polarity invariant"
, and "what are invariant functors":

[nLab] polarity in type theory
My intuition tells me this is the answer - but I have too little math / logic background to understand most of it (and to see how the parts that I do get connect to my question).

[blog] Polarity in Type Theory
Same.

[stackoverflow] Example of Invariant Functor?
The answer does mention the words "positive" and "negative", but it doesn't explain them, and neither do the linked resources. It does mention "HOAS",

[google search] higher order abstract syntax HOAS
but it doesn't look like what I'm looking for.

[hackage] layers package documentation
-> invariant functors
Even if it is relevant, I don't get it...

[ploeh blog] Invariant functors and Functors as invariant functors
No mention of "positive" or "negative", but these posts did lead me to Mark Seemann's articles series Functors, applicatives, and friends that looks compelling and comprehensive, but so far I didn't find anything there either (or I missed it..)

[nLab] invariant
Um, way above my head...



Note that the nlab page on invariants is unrelated to invariant functors; only a naming coincidence.

I asked this same question a while ago and got a few links in response: https://twitter.com/puffnfresh/status/1377474203444637701

I'm not aware of where the terminology comes from, but it's a way to analyse a parametrically polymorphic type in order to figure out whether it's covariant, contravariant, or invariant.
FWIW, I find the explanation given in Thinking with Types (ch. 3) very useful and easy to follow. It's a short chapter (only six pages), but still too long to reproduce here (and besides, I'd be violating the author's copyright). The gist of the matter, though, is that

"Type variables which appear exclusively in positive position are covariant. Those exclusively in negative position are contravariant. And type variables which find themselves in both become invariant."

For a simple function type like a -> b, a is in negative position and b in positive position. Thus, a -> b is covariant in b, but contravariant in a.
There's a little more to it, though, because how do you analyze a type like (Int -> a) -> Int or (a -> Int) -> Int (examples from the book)?
There's a tiny bit of easily digestible algebra involved in finding the answers to questions like these, and the notion of positive and negative position helps with that.
To be clear, I'm not affiliated with Sandy Maguire in any way; I just liked the book. I'm sure this kind of analysis comes from somewhere else, but (if I should have one gripe against the book), Sandy Maguire doesn't provide citations.

You can think of -> as a binary type operator that is contravariant in the first argument and covariant in the second argument (the hom-functor). That is, in order to go from a -> b to a' -> b', you need functions a' -> a and b -> b' to build the composite a' -> a -> b -> b'.
Thus -> "reverses" the polarity/variance of its first argument. A positive position is one that is covariant and a negative position is one that is contravariant. Here are some examples, with positive positions annotated with a ⁺ and negative positions with a ⁻:

a⁻ -> a⁺
a⁻ -> b⁻ -> c⁺
(a⁺ -> b⁻) -> c⁺
Either a⁺ (a⁻ -> ⊥)

The last example might shed some light on the terminology: thinking of types as propositions, an element of a⁺ is a witness that a holds, while an element of a⁻ -> ⊥ is a refutation of a.
If a type operator F is such that a only appears in positive position in F a, then F can be extended to a (covariant) endofunctor on the category of types. If a only appears in negative position in F a, then F can be extended to a contravariant endofunctor. On the other hand, if a occurs both in positive and negative position, then we need morphisms in both directions to go from F a to F a'. One way to phrase this mathematically is that F extends to a functor from the core of the category of types: the subcategory consisting only of the isomorphisms.
